# Conditional formatting based on portion of text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Is there a better way to specify conditional formatting based on another cell? For example, I have specified a **Custom formula** as the following (which works):

```
=or($A:$A="bar foo", $A:$A="baz foo")
```

But I would really prefer to match a partial. Something like (this doesn't work):

```
=$A:$A*="foo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For partial string matches, use [`regexmatch`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en), such as

```
=regexmatch($A:$A, "foo$")
```

to match any string ending with "foo".

---

Aside: I find it easier to enter conditional formatting rules as they apply to the single cell in the upper left corner. So my version would be `=regexmatch($A1, "foo$")`. If the formatting rule is applied, say, to the range `C:F`, then for E3 the formula would be automatically remapped to `=regexmatch($A3, "foo$")`