# Conditional Formatting - Custom Formula - Text Contains

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have dates in column B that include weekdays in the following format: `DDD, MMM DD, YYY` (For example, `Sat, Jan 19, 2019`).

I want each row to auto format to a specific background colour based on the weekday in column B:

- if B1 contains `Sat` I want row 1 to turn blue
- if B100 contains `Sat` I want row 100 to turn blue

I have tried using suggestions from these threads like `regexmatch()` and `countif()`:

- [Conditional formatting based on portion of text](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85753/conditional-formatting-based-on-portion-of-text)
- [Finding partial texts in conditional formatting custom formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723102/finding-partial-texts-in-conditional-formatting-custom-formula-is)

But neither of these seem to work for me.

I am at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **conditional formatting of whole row with a custom formula: `=IF(LEFT($A1, 3)="Sat", 1, 0)`**

---

[image: 6]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! That works brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

- **create conditional formatting based on `Text starts with`** like:

---

[image: 1]

Comment: This doesn't work. I need the entire row to turn Blue. Hence my mention of using Custom Formula and not Text starts with, or Text contains.

Comment: @RaphaelFriess I see, another answer provided... cheers